# why can I autowire or inject pojo but I can't autowire or inject RestTemplate

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I read a lot in this forum about similiar problems happening when trying to Autowire a pojo and usually the answer to fix is related to `component-scan` or `@Component`/`@Controller`. But in my case I manage to autowire my pojo (Mas60010) but I can not autowire `RestTemplate` or `ObjectMapper` and possibly any other object from a package that I didn't code.

To make simple, I just mention `RestTemplate`. What I am doing wrong? I guess the problem is either with libraries or configuration. Note: please, don't point this question as duplicate only by showing a question that is related to his own pojo. You can see that it is not my question because I am able to manage this. The problem is with classes inside jars included in my project.

```
package com.ma.mhe.log.handler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class Lo_DisplayHandler extends Lo_Handler {

       @Autowired private Mas60010 _mas60010; //this work perfectly
       @Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate; //this always cause nullPointException
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ma.mhe.log.handle, com.ma.mhe.log.domain" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:restServices.properties"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>

<!-- I was expecting this line to be enouth -->   
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
</bean>
```

//Pojo - I can autowire it

```
package com.ma.log.domain;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Mas60010 {
```

All libraries

- "validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar"
- "aopalliance-1.0.jar"
- "commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"
- "db2java.zip"
- "hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar"
- "hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.1.0.Final.jar"
- "jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar"
- "jackson-core-2.2.3.jar"
- "jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar"
- "slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"
- "spring-aop-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-context-support-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-expression-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
- "upload.jar"

//StackTrace

```
[12/17/14 10:38:54:243 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ma.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler.lastPage(Lo_DisplayHandler.java:181)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:246 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ma.mhe.log.Lo_Servlet.doDisDis(Lo_Servlet.java:164)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:248 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ma.mhe.log.Lo_Servlet.doProcess(Lo_Servlet.java:51)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:250 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ma.mhe.log.Lo_Servlet.doPost(Lo_Servlet.java:24)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:253 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:255 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:257 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:260 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:767)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:261 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:469)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:262 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1060)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:263 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1377)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:265 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:185)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:266 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ma.mhe.Mhe_ControllerServlet.doProcess(Mhe_ControllerServlet.java:83)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:267 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ma.mhe.Mhe_ControllerServlet.doPost(Mhe_ControllerServlet.java:32)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:268 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:269 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:270 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:271 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:767)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:272 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:469)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:273 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1060)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:275 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:276 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:277 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:277 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:776)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:278 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:279 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
[12/17/14 10:38:54:280 CST] 00000033 SystemErr                                                    R        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile enabled features

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
        <feature>json-1.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

//class Lo_DisplayHandler

```
@Component
public class Lo_DisplayHandler extends Lo_Handler {

       public Lo_DisplayHandler() {
              super();
       }

       @Autowired
       private Mas60010 _mas60010;
       @Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;


       public Lo_DisplayHandler(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
              super();

              this.request  = request;
              this.response = response;
       }



       public void lastPage() {
              //RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); //if I uncomment this line and comment the @Autowired it will work
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              try{


                     myPojoParameters...       

                     //the next line rises nullPointExcepetion if I choose Autowired instead of new RestTemplate()
                     LogDisplay _l = restTemplate.postForObject(myServiceUrl,myPojoParameters, LogDisplay.class);
                     Lo_DisplayRecord lo_DisplayRecord = new Lo_DisplayRecord();

                     ArrayList<Lo_DisplayRecord> displayValues = new ArrayList<Lo_DisplayRecord>();

                     for(int i = 0; i < _l.getDisplayValues().size(); i++){
                           lo_DisplayRecord = mapper.convertValue(_l.getDisplayValues().get(i), Lo_DisplayRecord.class);
                           displayValues.add(lo_DisplayRecord);
                     }

                     Some not relevant operations...                
              }catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
```

[image: Stack Trace]

//Lo_Servlet

```
package com.ma.mhe.log;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.ma.mhe.Mhe_Servlet;
import com.ma.mhe.PageFlow;
import com.ma.mhe.log.handler.*;

public class Lo_Servlet extends Mhe_Servlet {


                private String _module = "lo       public void init(){}

                public void doPost(
                                javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                                javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
                                throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
                                doProcess(request,response);                                                 
                }

                public void doGet(
                                javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                                javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
                                throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
                                doProcess(request,response); 
                }
                public void doProcess(
                                javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                                javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
                                throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
                                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                                int val = setTask(session,request);

                                switch(val){

                                //FILTER PAGE
                                case 1:doFilRep(request,response);break;                                                                                                                                                         
                                case 2:doFilFil(request,response);break;                            
                                case 3:doFilDis(request,response);break;           
                                case 4:doFilDef(request,response);break;

                                //DISPLAY PAGE
                                case 5:doDisRep(request,response);break;                                                                                                                                                        
                                case 6:doDisFil(request,response);break;           
                                case 7:doDisDis(request,response);break;

       private void doDisDis(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

              Lo_DisplayHandler display = null;
              try{
                     display = new Lo_DisplayHandler(request,response);

                     display.lastPage();
              }catch(Exception e){
                                   }finally{
                     display = null;
              }


       }
```

//web.xml
    
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
           MHE

```
       <servlet>
              <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

       <listener>
              <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                     <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>      

       <servlet>
              <description>
              </description>
              <display-name>Lo_Servlet</display-name>
              <servlet-name>Lo_Servlet</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>com.ma.mhe.log.Lo_Servlet</servlet-class>

       </servlet>
... others servlets configuration like this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void doDisDis(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    Lo_DisplayHandler display = null;
    try {
        display = new Lo_DisplayHandler(request,response);
        display.lastPage();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        display = null;
    }
}
```

The code above is creating new instances of the `Lo_DisplayHandler` class. Those instances aren't managed by Spring, so basically the `@Autowired` is pretty useless here. Spring will only do dependency injection into beans it knows.

Assuming that you are using the `ContextLoaderListener` to load the spring configuration you can use the `WebApplicationContextUtils` to get the `ApplicationContext`. You can use this to get the beans you want.

```
private void doDisDis(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    Lo_DisplayHandler display = null;
    try {
        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());          
        display = context.getBean(Lo_DisplayHandler.class, request, response);
        display.lastPage();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        display = null;
    }
}
```

To make this work you have to make your `Lo_DisplayHandler` a prototype bean, this means each time a `getBean` call is done a new instance is created. For this add the `@Scope` annotation to the class.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Lo_DisplayHandler extends Lo_Handler { ... }
```

A final note instead of doing a lookup for the `ApplicationContext` each time you need one, you might want to do it once in the `init` method of the servlet and store it as an instance variable. Saves you a line of code and some performance.