# why autowired variable in prototype scope works only in the first instance

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, scope, resttemplate

I am trying to Autowired RestTemplate and I am using the suggestion from [why can I autowire or inject pojo but I can't autowire or inject RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513495/why-can-i-autowire-or-inject-pojo-but-i-cant-autowire-or-inject-resttemplate) . Unfortunetlly I am facing a problem from the second instantiation. The variable restTemplate works only once. After that, it is null. I guess that I might have done some mistake in `dispatcher-servlet` or `web.xml` config.

I know that the scope prototype creates a new instance every time it is called but I wasn't expect the auto wired `RestTemplate` to be null in the second instance. All others autowired variables runs perfectly every calls.
I saw some similiar threads and all of them ends up with some solution related to create a scope proxy. I changed to `@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` but I got the error "Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition". Honestly I can't imagine this as the right direction for my case as I have problem only with restTemplate and in the second evoke of context.getBean.

```
//the process starts here

    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
                   display = context.getBean(Lo_DisplayHandler.class, request, response);

                         display.lastPage();
```

DisplayHandler

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Lo_DisplayHandler extends Lo_Handler {
 //this constructor runs twice when the application start
       public Lo_DisplayHandler() {
              super();
       }
```

this constructor runs every time the bean is get from context (context.getBean(Lo_DisplayHandler.class, request, response)). The first time `Lo_DisplayHandler` is created restTemplate is filled in but from the second time forward restTemplate is `null`

```
public Lo_DisplayHandler(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    super();
    //get DB2 connection and set some data in session
}


@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
 //restTemplate will exist only in the first time
LogDisplay _l = restTemplate.postForObject(RestProperties.getUrl() + RestProperties.getFirstpage(),_mas60010, LogDisplay.class);
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

           <context:annotation-config />
           <mvc:annotation-driven />
           <context:component-scan base-package="com.myCompany.mhe.common.controller, com.myCompany.mhe.log.handler, com.myCompany.mhe.utilities, com.myCompany.mhe.log.domain, com.myCompany.mhe.log.storedprocedure" />
           <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:restServices.properties"/>
           <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />

           <!—-
    If take the next three beans definition from here to applicationContext.xml and change contextConfigLocation to point to applicationContext.xml instead of mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml my controller stops to work
    -->

           <bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />
           <bean
               class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
               <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
               <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
               <property name="arguments">
                   <list>
                       <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature">READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS</value>
                       <value>true</value>
                   </list>
               </property>
           </bean>

           <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
               <property name="messageConverters">
                   <list>
                       <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                           <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                       </bean>
                   </list>
               </property>
           </bean>


    </beans>
```

web.xml

```
  <servlet>
          <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

//Exception after default constructor removed

```
[WARNING ] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
Error creating bean with name 'lo_Controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.mhe.Mhe_Handler com.mycompany.mhe.common.controller.Lo_Controller.mhe_Handler; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lo_DisplayHandler' defined in file [C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycompany\mhe\log\handler\Lo_DisplayHandler.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mycompany.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler.<init>()
[ERROR   ] Context initialization failed
Error creating bean with name 'lo_Controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.mhe.Mhe_Handler com.mycompany.mhe.common.controller.Lo_Controller.mhe_Handler; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lo_DisplayHandler' defined in file [C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycompany\mhe\log\handler\Lo_DisplayHandler.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mycompany.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler.<init>()
```

Comment: One thing is that you are duplicating all of your beans, both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` are loading  the same configuration. Resulting in all beans being loaded twice. Also `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`. This is also why you see the default constructor run twice because everything is duplicated.

Comment: Another thing I would remove the default constructor as that isn't what you want to use, only leave the one taking the request and response.

Comment: I know I load the same configuration twice but how do you separate the configurations? Which one you place in a file loaded by ContextLoaderListener and which in -servlet? I tried to place only RestTemplate and MapperObject in applicationContext but this doesn't work (see my comment above "If take the next...". The only way I was able to make both Autowired RestTemplate and Context.getBean(Lo_DisplayHandler.class...) works was by pointing ContextLoaderListener to the same configuration loaded by DispatcherServlet. Is this the reason for restTemplate = null in second call but filled in in first

Comment: As long as I can remenber, if I "...remove the default constructor..." it will not compile because @Component requires default constructor explicitly coded. But the most important to me, is this possible cause of my origin issue: restTemplate filled in when first Context.getBean happens but null at second one?

Comment: @Component doesn't require a default constructor.

Comment: And it certainly wouldn't lead to a compiler exception... You should split your context in two 2 files, generiek/global available beans should be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` (datasources, services, daos, etc.) web related stuff (controllers, view resolvers etc) should be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. In your case your handler classes should also be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` as you are using `WebApplicationContextUtils` which accesses the root context (loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: That is including the `RestTemplate`. The `DispatcherServlet` can access beans loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` but not the other way around.

Comment: With your statement "@Component doesn't require a default constructor" in mind what could be the reason for the log errors I pasted? It was caused after I remove the default constructor.

Comment: I added <bean id="lo_DisplayHandler" class="com.mastercard.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler" scope="prototype"/> in applicationContext.xml loaded by ContextLoaderListener and now I am getting restTemplate null even in the first call. Note: I can't take out the default empty constructor from the component Lo_DisplayHandler otherwise it doesn't compile.

Comment: Do you think I should focus on in one of these topics from Spring DOCS: 5.2.1 Configuration metadata: use Spring’s integration with AspectJ to configure objects that have been created outside the control
of an IoC container. 5.3 Bean overview: 
the ApplicationContext implementations also permit the
registration of existing objects that are created outside the container by accessing the ApplicationContext’s BeanFactory via the method getBeanFactory(). 5.4.6 Method injection: implement ApplicationContextAware. 5.5.5 Custom scopes and 5.8.3 Customizing instantiation logic with a FactoryBean

Comment: There is no sensible reason why it wouldn't compile, that simply doesn't make any sense... I still strongly suggest to remove it, if it doesn't compile there is probably some other class using the default constructor, which you should fix. You can use aspectj and `@Configurable` but that greatly increases the complexity of the deployment and running of your application. What you have should simply work, there must be something still missing in your setup. Make sure you have either `<context:annotation-config />` or `<context:component-scan />` else annotations don't work.

Comment: Also your bean is a `@Component` with `@Scope` so it doesn't make sense to add it to the xml at all. That is if you have a `<context:component-scan />`. Either put it in xml and remove `@Component` or remove it from xml and use component-scanning, don't do both.

Comment: The method lastPage are invoked from two places: first time it is evoked from Lo_DisplayHandler which extends HttpServlet. After the user change some filters criterias, the method lastPage is evoked from Lo_FilterHandler which doesn't extend HttpServlet. Your suggestion WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext()) don't run in Lo_FilterHandler because GenericServlet isn't implemented. Is there a way to get Lo_DisplayHandler from a class which doesn't extend HttpServlet? Maybe by looking up it? Or maybe by adding @Component to Lo_FilterHandler + autoScanned?

Comment: In your `Filter` in the `init` method you can obtain the `ServletContext` from the `FilterConfig` and use that later to obtain the context. Or use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` to be able to move your filter to the spring context and have it configured by spring (you could then use dependency injection to autowire the dependencies).

Comment: Although you see the word "Filter" it is not a filter from Java perspective. I mean, it doesn't implement Filter neither extend some class implementing Filter. Moreover, in this project there isn't a single <filter-mapping> in web.xml. Lo_FilterHandler receives the name filter because it uses some saved parameters from session to narrow certain search.

Comment: Then I cannot help you :). Get a handle to the `ServletContext` somehow and retrieve the applicationcontext or find a way to autowire the thing.

Comment: Thanks. How can I set your last comment as useful?