# how call a declared constructor using ApplicationContextAware and pass HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse

Tags: spring, servlets, constructor, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

I am using ApplicationContextAware to get a bean from a legacy code. I need to pass two parameters to the constructor. When I use WebApplicationContextUtils it is easy but I didn't find how to do the same using ApplicationContextAware. Basically, I need to pass HttpServletRequest request and HttpServletResponse response to the constructor of the bean retrieved from ApplicationContextAware.

//using WebApplicationContextUtils

```
public class ClassA extends HttpServlet{
       private void methodA(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
          Lo_DisplayHandler display = null;

          ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

          display = context.getBean(Lo_DisplayHandler.class, request, response);
       }
}
```

//using ApplicationContextAware

```
/*
Although it doesn’t extend HttpServlet this class receives HttpServletRequest request and HttpServletResponse response in its constructor and I want to pass them to a bean retrieved from ApplicationContextAware 
*/
public class ClassB { 

       private HttpServletRequest request;
       private HttpServletResponse response;

       public ClassB (HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

              this.request  = request;
              this.response = response;
       }

       public void methodB(){

       Lo_DisplayHandler handler = null;

       //the doubt is here: How can I pass request,response to the constructor
       handler = (Lo_DisplayHandler) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("lo_DisplayHandler");
}
```

//the invoked bean

```
@Lazy(value=true)
public class Lo_DisplayHandler {
       //how call this constructor from SpringApplicationContext.getBean?
       public Lo_DisplayHandler(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
```

//the use of ApplicationContextAware

```
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    CONTEXT = context;
  }

  public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
    return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
  }
}
```

//aplicationContext.xml

```
      <bean id="springApplicationContext" class="com.myCompany.mhe.util.context.SpringApplicationContext"/>
      <bean id="lo_DisplayHandler" class="com.myCompany.mhe.log.handler.Lo_DisplayHandler" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true"/>
```

//web.xml

```
<servlet>
              <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
       <context-param>
              <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
       </context-param>
       <listener>
              <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
```

//Solutions found

```
public static Object getBean(String beanName, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
      //OPTION 1
      //return CONTEXT.getBean( beanName, request, response);

       //OPTION 2
       BeanFactory factory = (BeanFactory) CONTEXT;
       return (Lo_DisplayHandler)factory.getBean("lo_DisplayHandler", request,response);

  }
```

Comment: The same as the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513495/why-can-i-autowire-or-inject-pojo-but-i-cant-autowire-or-inject-resttemplate) question of yours.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you didn't understand my question. How can I pass two parameters to the constructor when using ApplicationContextAware? In other words, how I call a definied constructor instead of default when using ApplicationContextAware? Kindly see in my question that SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware. SpringApplicationContext.getBean gets the object by String name and there isn't other acceptable parameter. On the other hand, WebApplicationContextUtils...getBean allow to send Request and Response parameter.

Comment: Fix your method... The problem is in your own defined `getBean` method. Just add an `Object... args` argument to that method... Things you cannot pass are impossible to pass on... It has nothing to do with `ApplicationContextAware` just your implementation of the `getBean` method.

Comment: Thanks. So I will try pass the parameters via getters and setters. How I point your last answer as solution?

Comment: Why would you pass them through getters/setters? That isn't what I was talking about... Just make a `getBean` method to mirror the one from the `ApplicationContext`. I would mirror [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-), as that will also save you a cast.

Comment: Firstly, it was lack of attention that I didn't see that it was possible to pass request and response as argument. Secondly, if I understood correctly uour last suggestion, I can't see the use of BeanFactory saving a cast (please look my update origin question at the end. I edited it).

Comment: Have you actually looked at the method I linked you to? You are currently doing a lookup by name, which returns an `Object`. There are also `getBean` methods that take a type which return an actual object of that type (due to generics). That will save you the cast.

Comment: You are right! A last doubt very close related to the original question:  I know that using the "push" method (e.g. IoC by injection) is the recommended for unit and integrated tests. Unfortunetly, in my scenario I am obligated to use ApplicationContext/WebApplicationContextUtils.getBean to lock up the Beans (e.g. "pull" method). About to use mock tests, should I expect (1) be impossible, (2) very dificult or (3) almost straigh forward as if it was @Autowired? If the answer is 1 or 2, any well known workaround will be usefull for a north in my searchs.